# Employee Birthday Reminder

Tags: list, workflow, custom, office-365

I have SharePoint Online and I have custom list for employee profile information.

I need to create workflow to send me/or HR Dept e-mail reminder before employee birthday by (x) days. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Try to customize this workflow to send a email to HR manager, not to a person as in the below link. Follow [this source](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2014/04/18/SharePoint-2013-_2D00_-Creating-a-Birthday-Reminder-Workflow.aspx) around implementing my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/356358fd-071c-40f6-8f35-a90e08ccdcdf/automatic-workflow-for-birthday-reminders?forum=crmdevelopment
I guess i am later here, but for others follow above link.

Answer (score 0):

Another dead simple approach could be to do a people search for people:birthday - xdays,  and set an alert for that query